# Where do I define navHostActivity in my MainActivity to start navigation using Navigation Component

Tags: android, mvvm

I have very basic app in which I have 2 activities namely MainActivity and DetailActivity (I have no fragments), I have defined nav_graph as below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@+id/firstActvity">

    <activity
        android:id="@+id/firstActvity"
        android:name="com.example.searchbarmocksample.activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="First Activity">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/nav_graph_actFirstActvity"
            app:destination="@id/secondActvity" />

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:id="@+id/secondActvity"
        android:name="com.example.searchbarmocksample.activities.DetailActivity"
        android:label="Second Activity" />
</navigation>

Now MainActivity code -

    class MainActivity : BaseActivity(), Injectable {
    
        lateinit var bankListViewModel: BankListViewModel
    
        @Inject
        lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory
    
     override fun layoutRes(): Int {
            return R.layout.activity_main
        }
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            AndroidInjection.inject(this)
    
            bankListViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(BankListViewModel::class.java)
    
            if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                bankListViewModel.getBankList.observe(this, Observer { list ->
                    val binding: ActivityMainBinding =
                        DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
                    binding.bank = list
                    binding.itemClickListener = itemClickListener
                    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)
                    binding.executePendingBindings()
                })
            } else {
            }
        }
    
        fun isNetworkAvailable(): Boolean {
            val cm = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                val n = cm.activeNetwork
                if (n != null) {
                    val nc = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(n)
                    //It will check for both wifi and cellular network
                    return nc!!.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) || nc.hasTransport(
                        NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI
                    )
                }
                return false
            } else {
                val netInfo = cm.activeNetworkInfo
                return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting
            }
        }
    
        private val itemClickListener: ItemClickListener = object : ItemClickListener {
            override fun onClick(bankList: BankListModel) {
                val bundle = Bundle()
                bundle.putSerializable("data", bankList)
                Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.nav_graph_actFirstActvity, bundle)
            }
        }
    
    }
```

I am not able to navigate to DetailAcitity from MainActivity. I think I have not used any host activity, that's why I am not able to navigate. But I am not able to find a way as to where I have to define my navHostActivity so to correct my code. Please can anybody help?

Comment: navigation is used for fragment. you can startActivity for this case.

Comment: Yes, I can do with startActivity as well but can I do it using navigation component? That's what I want to achieve.

Comment: Refer this: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started . use for fragment only.